# Conversion of list of JSON array to a single object in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have an array list which needs to be converted to a single object with few of the values from array list using TypeScript in Angular 8. Below is the array:

```
"arrayList": [{
    "name": "Testname1",
    "value": "abc"
  },
  {
    "name": "Testname2",
    "value": "xyz"
  }
]
```

This needs to be converted to the below format,

```
data: {
  "Testname1": "abc",
  "Testname2": "xyz",
}
```

No matter how much i try, i end up creating a list instead of a single object. Can you please help on the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follows,

```js
 
var arr =  [
            {
                "name": "Testname1",
                "value": "abc"
            },
            {
                "name": "Testname2",
                "value": "xyz"
            }
           ];

var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  result[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as the following:

```js
const arrayList = [{ "name": "Testname1", "value": "abc" }, { "name": "Testname2", "value": "xyz" }];

const data = arrayList.reduce((a, {name, value}) => {
  a[name] = value;
  return a;
}, {});

const result = { data };

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.map()` to get a list of `[name, value]` entries, then use `Object.fromEntries()` to convert to an object:

```js
const arrayList = [{ "name": "Testname1", "value": "abc" }, { "name": "Testname2", "value": "xyz" }];

const result = Object.fromEntries(arrayList.map(({ name, value }) => [name, value]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code

```js
const rawData = {
  "arrayList": [{
      "name": "Testname1",
      "value": "abc"
    },
    {
      "name": "Testname2",
      "value": "xyz"
    }
  ]
};

const updatedData = {
  data: {}
};

for (const item of rawData["arrayList"]) {
  updatedData.data[item.name] = item.value;
}

console.log(updatedData);
```